# How do I add another "AND" to a "MATCH AGAINST" query

Tags: mysql, match, where-clause, against

I'm a newbie and I cannot get this query return any results. 
How do I add `AND paginas_taal = 'ned'` to the query below?
Anyone has a clue?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT paginas_tekst AS Tekst, paginas_naam AS Naam, paginas_button AS Button, 'paginas' AS Tabel, '0' AS Parent,
  MATCH (
    paginas_tekst
  )
  AGAINST (
    'shoppers'
  ) AS Relevance
  FROM paginas
  WHERE MATCH (
    paginas_tekst
  )
  AGAINST (
    '+shoppers'
    IN BOOLEAN
    MODE
  )
  HAVING Relevance > 0.2
) AS testtabel
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

TIA
Gr. Hans

Comment: @liquorvicar: I tried to put the extra 'and' on several places inside the query, but that did not work. Been searching for days now, but can't find an answer. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra AND clause anywhere in the WHERE clause. Also note that you don't need your outer query so you should be able to wrte

```
SELECT paginas_tekst AS Tekst, paginas_naam AS Naam, paginas_button AS Button, 
    'paginas' AS Tabel, '0' AS Parent,
    MATCH ( paginas_tekst ) AGAINST ( 'shoppers' ) AS Relevance
FROM paginas
WHERE MATCH ( paginas_tekst ) AGAINST ( '+shoppers' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) 
  AND paginas_taal = 'ned'
HAVING Relevance > 0.2
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```